# Why IDA debugger on android doesn't show all threads?

Tags: ida, debugging, android, debuggers

My `IDA` Version is `IDA Pro 7.5 SP2`. And I'm trying to debug a `.so` file inside a `.apk` file.

Here's what I've done:

- download a `x86_64` system image android emulator from `android studio`
- install that `.apk` on emulator and run it.
- push `android_x64_server` inside `/dbgsrv` of `IDA` installation folder into `/data` folder of emulator.
  (`adb push ida-folder/dbgsrv/android_x64_server /data`)
- execute the following command:

```
adb shell
cd /data
chmod 777 ./android_x86_server  
./android_x86_server
```

- back into windows terminal, and execute `adb forward tcp:23946 tcp:23946`
- open `IDA Pro`, select `remote linux debugger` attach to apk's process

And the "Threads" window only show one thread, which is not true because when I execute `ps -T -p [pid]` inside adb shell, and found that the process is a multi-thread application.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since Android 10.0, it has move some of its important library into different path ( including `libc.so` )
so IDA can't automatically found where it is like it used to.

You need to execute `export IDA_LIBC_PATH=/apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so` to tell IDA where `libc.so` can be found.

Answer (score -1):

for debugging a 64 bit process.

`export IDA_LIBC_PATH=/apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so`

Comment: This could as well been a comment to the existing answer. Doesn't add much information of its own.

Comment: OP does not have the Comment privilege though. I'd encourage OP to elaborate a bit and provide a full and meaningful answer